# Remove the inbuilt filter contact ID from Incident Reports in Customer Portal in Oracle RightNow

Tags: oracle, rightnow-crm, oracle-service-cloud

This is about displaying a "Report on Incidents" based on the "Organization" on the Customer Portal. We will be entering the Organization in an input box and then on clicking on "submit". The Incident Report should be displayed only for that Organization.

This is happening but the "Logged In" contacts Id (c_id) is also getting passed as a filter to that Incident Report.

Is it possible to remove the c_id filter that's imposed on the above Incident report? How do I remove this contact ID filter from Incident report?

Someone suggested to use the pre_report_get_data hook and then unset the Contact ID (c_id) filter. But I was not able to figure out how to do that.

Can someone give me a code snippet to remove the c_id filter using pre_report_get_data hook? Or some other solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the report that you want to edit to a new version, then edit the filters of the report as you see fit.  You won't be able to edit the default canned reports directly, but with a copy, you can edit it completely.

## EDIT

Contact filters are always applied on Customer Portal filters because of the user model on Customer Portal.  CP expects that a user on the web is a specific customer and should only have access to contact data that is specific to the particular contact in the user session.  This is a security mechanism and is working as intended.

If the goal is to display data from reports that might have contact data related to it, but should be exposed to all contacts, then you should probably write a custom widget that runs a ROQL or Analytics API query directly, but be wary of the potential to expose other customer data if implemented incorrectly.

If you want to use the pre_report_get_data hook, then it's pretty simple to enable the hook in the settings/hooks.php file.  Point the hook to the model and method that you want the hook to call.  Then, edit the passed array of data to unset c_id from the filters array, as was mentioned in the other post.

```
$rnHooks['pre_report_get'][] = array(
   'class' => 'filter_report',
   'function' => 'report_run',
   'filepath' => ''
);
```

That tells the hook engine to call the `report_run()` method in the `filter_report` model.  These are typically example code files in CP, so you should have most of the work already done to implement that hook.

```
function report_run($hookData)
{
    if($hookData['data']['reportId'] == '100335') //Change the report ID to the report that you need to call  
    {
        unset($hookData['data']['filters']['c_id']); //you'll need to lookup the key of the filter in the report to figure out which one to unset
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. But I made the mistake of not clearly explaining the problem. I have updated the question now. Also the report works just fine in the report explorer and shows incidents belonging to only that organization. But when used in the customer portal , the contact id filter is getting passed automatically without me doing anything. Can you please check my above question again and see if you know of any solutions. Thanks a ton for taking the time to answer this question. Cheers.

Comment: And one more thing I forgot to add Scott,  I was using a custom report in the first place without any Contact Id filters. Please see if you can help in any way. So many requirements for reports in customer portal, but this stupid Contact Id of the logged In user keeps applying as a filter. I understand its for security purposes but I could do that myself right. Thanks.